# C++ Loop Not Looping Appropriately

Tags: c++, loops

I have an array of 20 x 20 that outputs how hot a plate is. I need to reiterate through a loop until no cell in the array changes more than 0.1 degree(I refresh the values through every iteration. How would you monitor the largest change for any cell in an array in order to determine when to stop iterating? Right now I have tried, but the below doesn't output correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
const int NEIGHBORS = 4;

void initialize(double hot_plate[][ARRAY_SIZE]);
bool writeFile(const double HOT_PLATE[][ARRAY_SIZE],
           const string FILE_NAME);

double sum_cell(const double HOT_PLATE[][ARRAY_SIZE],
            const int CELL_X, const int CELL_Y);

int main()
{
double hot_plate[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];
double hot_plate_prev[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];

initialize(hot_plate);

string file_name = "hot_plate.csv";

//accuracy up to 4 decmials
int runs = 724;
double hot_plate[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];
double hot_plate_prev[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];

while (true)
{
 // This is your code
 for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1 && j > 0 && j < ARRAY_SIZE - 1)
        {
            hot_plate[i][j] = sum_cell(hot_plate, j, i);
        }
    }
}

bool theSame = true;
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (abs(hot_plate[i][j] - hot_plate_prev[i][j]) < 0.1)
        {
            theSame = false;
        }
        hot_plate_prev[i][j] = hot_plate[i][j];
    }
}

if (!theSame) break;
}
}

if (writeFile(hot_plate, file_name))
{
    cout << "File wrote correctly\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "The file did not write!\n";
}

//system("pause");

return 0;
}


double sum_cell(const double HOT_PLATE[][ARRAY_SIZE],
            const int CELL_X, const int CELL_Y)
{
/* This code should never go out of bounds as it's in an if statement
   if (i > 0 && i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1 && j > 0 && j < ARRAY_SIZE - 1)
*/
double cell_num = HOT_PLATE[CELL_X - 1][CELL_Y]; // Top
cell_num += HOT_PLATE[CELL_X][CELL_Y - 1]; // Left
cell_num += HOT_PLATE[CELL_X][CELL_Y + 1]; // Right
cell_num += HOT_PLATE[CELL_X + 1][CELL_Y]; // Bottom

cell_num /= NEIGHBORS;

return cell_num;
}

// setup the Array so all values are defined when starting
void initialize(double hot_plate[][ARRAY_SIZE])
{
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == ARRAY_SIZE - 1)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == ARRAY_SIZE - 1)
            {
                hot_plate[i][j] = 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                hot_plate[i][j] = 100.0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hot_plate[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
}

// Write the data to the CSV file
bool writeFile(const double HOT_PLATE[][ARRAY_SIZE],
           const string FILE_NAME)
{
// open the file
ofstream fout(FILE_NAME);
if (fout.fail())
  return false;

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
   {
       fout << HOT_PLATE[i][j];
       if ( j < ARRAY_SIZE - 1)
       {
           fout << ", ";
       }
       else if (i != ARRAY_SIZE - 1)
       {
           fout << endl;
       }
   }
}

// close the input stream from the file.
fout.close();
return true;
}
```

Comment: `.1` isn't in your code anywhere, that might be related to your bug.

Comment: This doesn't loop until no cell changes by more than 0.1 degrees, it simply loops 724 times.  Your question title is highly misleading

Comment: hot_plate[i][j] = sum_cell(hot_plate, j, i); // ^^^^^^^
Are you sure you want to perform matrix transpose?

Comment: whoops that was an old version

Comment: Code posted doesn't compile, you "fixed it" wrong.  http://ideone.com/duvXU

Comment: haha I am fairly new to C++..

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your `while` loop, you can set a boolean variable called something like `allSmallChanges` to `true`.  In your inner `if` statement, you can check to see if the change to `hot_plate[i][j]` is "too big".  If it is too big, then set `allSmallChanges` to false.  Then, just before the end of the `while` loop, you can `break` if `allSmallChanges` is still true.

If you don't want to have that cap of 724 iterations, you can get rid of your `runs` variable, and change the loop to `while(true)`.

Note: The code in the question got changed after I wrote this answer.  I'm not sure this answer still applies.  However, I'm also sure that will be the last change to the code in the question.  So, I'll leave this answer as-is for now.

Comment: `while(biggest_change_this_time >= 0.1)`

Comment: @MooingDuck: yup, that'd work too, although you'd have to declare that outside the loop and initialize it to some value bigger than 0.1, then re-zero it inside the loop.

Comment: I just like it's readability.  You're right that it would have wierd initialization rules though.

Comment: Thanks, @MooingDuck... but now I'm not sure it makes much sense ;)

Comment: @user1751615... that should almost work.  Except it doesn't look like you set `hot_plate_prev[i][j]` before you compare against it.  And, although you could do it with an array, it's a bit wasteful.  You only need to track a single change.  So, in that inner `for` loop, you could say `double old_val = hot_plate[i][j]`.  Then, check against `old_val`.  That way only uses up one memory location, instead of 400.